# Improve javascript function to not allow key holding

Tags: javascript, keydown, keyup

I created a function which checks if forbidden characters were typed and removes them, everything works fine until user starts holding key. Could someone help to improve?

```
function tooltip(object, type) {
var id = object.getAttribute('id');
var element = document.getElementById(id);
var value = document.getElementById(id).value;
var tooltip = document.getElementById("tooltip");
var parent = '#'+object.parentNode.id;
var string = /[\-&^_=+{}?\[\]\\!\£/>,`~:;" ()|<*%#\$]/;
if (type == 'limited') {
  var text = 'text';
}

if (string.test(value)) {
  element.value = element.value.replace(string, '');

  if (!tooltip && value != '') {
     $(parent).append('<div id="tooltip"><div class="arrow arrow-down"></div>'+text+'</div>');
     setTimeout(function() {
        $(parent +' #tooltip').fadeOut(500);
        setTimeout(function() {
           $(parent +' #tooltip').remove();
        }, 500);
     }, 5000);
  }
 }
}

<input id="username" type="text" onkeyup="tooltip(this, 'limited')">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `onkeydown` event and add a pairing for `keydown` and `keyup` events like following.

```js
var marked = true;

$("#username").keydown(function(e) {
  if(!marked) {e.preventDefault(); return;}; // will return for long press
  marked = false;
});


function tooltip(object, type) {
    marked = true;
    var id = object.getAttribute('id');
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    var value = document.getElementById(id).value;
    var tooltip = document.getElementById("tooltip");
    var parent = '#' + object.parentNode.id;
    var string = /[\-&^_=+{}?\[\]\\!\£/>,`~:;" ()|<*%#\$]/;
    if (type == 'limited') {
      var text = 'text';
    }

    if (string.test(value)) {
      element.value = element.value.replace(string, '');

      if (!tooltip && value != '') {
        $(parent).append('<div id="tooltip"><div class="arrow arrow-down"></div>' + text + '</div>');
        setTimeout(function() {
          $(parent + ' #tooltip').fadeOut(500);
          setTimeout(function() {
            $(parent + ' #tooltip').remove();
          }, 500);
        }, 5000);
      }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="username" type="text" onkeyup="tooltip(this, 'limited')">
```

**EDIT** (as per comments)

```js
var marked = true;


$("#username").on('keydown keyup', function( e ) { 
  if(e.type=="keydown") { 
    if(!marked) {e.preventDefault(); return;}; // will return for long press
    marked = false;
  } else {
    marked = true;
    tooltip(e.currentTarget, 'limited');
  }
});

function tooltip(element, type) {
    var id = element.id;
    var value = element.value;
    var tooltip = document.getElementById("tooltip");
    var parent = '#' + element.parentNode.id;
    var string = /[\-&^_=+{}?\[\]\\!\£/>,`~:;" ()|<*%#\$]/;
    if (type == 'limited') {
      var text = 'text';
    }

    if (string.test(value)) {
      element.value = element.value.replace(string, '');

      if (!tooltip && value != '') {
        $(parent).append('<div id="tooltip"><div class="arrow arrow-down"></div>' + text + '</div>');
        setTimeout(function() {
          $(parent + ' #tooltip').fadeOut(500);
          setTimeout(function() {
            $(parent + ' #tooltip').remove();
          }, 500);
        }, 5000);
      }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="username" type="text">
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Just one last questions, is there any way to achieve this using all in one function?

Comment: Yes you can - `$("#username").on('keydown keyup', function( e ) { if(e.type=="keydown") { } else {}});`

Comment: Is this very ugly?: <input id="username" type="text" onkeydown="tooltip(this, 'limited')" onkeyup="tooltip(this, 'limited')">

Comment: @LifeIsShort - No. There are different ways of writing the same thing. It totally depends on your choice.

Comment: What I am really trying to achieve is to call one function on key up and that function will do all the job, including symbol check when someone types inside input field and prevent key holding. How to write one function which will include everything, all in one, without need to trigger onkeydown and onkeyup in input like in example which I provided in previous comment?

Comment: @LifeIsShort - You can do that. Refer to my previous comment with event handler. You can segregate the keyup and keydown events there and then move your code from 2 different functions to this one common function

Comment: Could you please combine it into one function and update your answer?

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and help. I wanted to put whole content into one function like this: 

function tooltip(element, type) { keyup/keydown events and all function content }

Comment: You can do the same by moving the tootlip function code in else block.